# Query is Giving Wrong Results

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, brackets

```
SELECT `bio_community_groups`.`id`, `bio_community_groups`.`name`, `bio_community_groups`.`description`, `bio_community_groups`.`members`
FROM `bio_community_groups`
WHERE `bio_community_groups`.`category_id` = '1'
AND `bio_community_groups`.`name` LIKE '%rock%'
OR `bio_community_groups`.`description` LIKE '%rock%'
```

Problem: there isn't group with `ID = 1`, but anyway... it gives me all groups where name or description is like `'%rock%'`.

Maybe brackets may help me? Where should I put them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you might be looking for :

```
SELECT `bio_community_groups`.`id`, `bio_community_groups`.`name`, `bio_community_groups`.`description`, `bio_community_groups`.`members`
FROM `bio_community_groups`
WHERE
( `bio_community_groups`.`category_id` = '1' )

AND 
( `bio_community_groups`.`name` LIKE '%rock%'
OR `bio_community_groups`.`description` LIKE '%rock%' );
```

In your original query, you will get results satisfying :

```
`bio_community_groups`.`description` LIKE '%rock%
```

whatever the category_id may be .

Answer (score 0):

`AND` precedes `OR` in MySQL. so your query is like (`bio_community_groups.category_id = '1'
AND bio_community_groups.name LIKE '%rock%')
OR (bio_community_groups.description LIKE '%rock%`). Just place the appropriate brackets to resolve this